# Getiing this error in google app engine 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

My web.xml. Please check the url-pattern here. is it correct or not

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AppEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pack.exp.AppEngineServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AppEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appengine</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

My jsp file is like this. It has a textfield and a button. want to pass the data provided in the text field to the servlet. and then displays the data on new page.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
       <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Insert title here</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         <form method="post" action="appengine">
            <fieldset>
             <legend>Text input</legend>
                 <p>
                 <label>Text box</label>
                  <input type="text"  name="myText"/> 
                 </p>

        <button name="submit-action" value="confirm" type="submit">Submit!</button>
          </fieldset>
                </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Servlet file goes like this.

```
    package pack.exp;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class AppEngineServlet extends HttpServlet 
    {

     @Override
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)    
         throws 
         ServletException, IOException 
     {
    String output= req.getParameter("myText");

     PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
     pw.println("Hello " + output);
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you have presented here. There must be some other code base that you must have uploaded to the App Engine. I took your code, ran it locally and deployed to the App Engine cloud too. Everything looks good for what you want to do.

Take a look : http://1.testappromin.appspot.com/test.jsp

Comment: @ Romin
when i am running i am getting the output as Hello null.
Ï want to display the textbox and submit button and when i click on that button then Hello + text(entered in the textbox) should be shown.
Please help me with this

Comment: If you are getting your local output at Hello null, I suspect that there is a mismatch in the name of the parameter "myText". Just check if there is a difference, even the case matters here.

Comment: @ Romin
i have checked it, its fine. what i am saying is i cant see the textbox and button defined in jsp page. When i click on available servlet on appengine i get  only Hello null, I want the textbox and button .

Comment: Ah ! ... If you directly point your servlet to appengine, then it will show Hello Null because it never got a chance to enter anything. Do one thing, change the href in the Available Servlets to index.html page where you have the form and it should work.

Comment: @ Romin
Where is the href? and my form is in NewFile.jsp not in index.html

Comment: The welcome file mentioned in the web.xml is index.html. In that file you will find the Available Servlets entry. You will find the HTML <a> elements. Go ahead and change the href to point to NewFile.jsp and then try.

Comment: @ Romin
I have changed the link like this
<td><a href="NewFile.jsp">AppEngine</a></td>
Now please check http://1.dev-shanx.appspot.com/   
When clicking on submit getting this error Error: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: IT seems that your /AppEngine Servlet code is having only doGet() method and not doPost(). Please check it carefully. I do not think there is any error apart from some obvious errors like that in your code.